# How can I see how if a Lucene StandardTokenizer has tokens without calling incrementToken()

Tags: lucene, tokenize

I just need to know if the results of tokenzing input results in any tokens, if it does fine, if it doesn't I do need to tokenize in another way. Trouble if it does have some tokens calling incToken() breaks things so that then I have to retokenize it when I shouldnt need to because it was okay the first time, how do I get round this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `incrementToken` then `reset`.